# SoundPool doesnt make any sound in android

Tags: android, soundpool

Im trying to play 3 midi files (200Kb each) simultaneously after loading them to the soundPool.
After the play command I unload each stream and release the soundPool.I set the volume to 1 and the phone isnt silence.(Sorry for the language).
There is no crushes or somthing.

What should i do?
thx in advance

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
soundPool.play(sound_id1, leftVolume, rightVolume, 1, 0, rate);
soundPool.play(sound_id2, leftVolume, rightVolume, 1, 0, rate);
soundPool.play(sound_id3, leftVolume, rightVolume, 1, 0, rate);
soundPool.unload(stream_id1);
soundPool.unload(stream_id2);
soundPool.unload(stream_id3);
soundPool.release();
```

EDIT:
When Im in debug mode and go over the play command it works great.
Tried to add a OnLoadCompleteListener still nothing.

Comment: Make sure you are allowing enough time for the audio to load, and that it is indeed loading correctly. Use SoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener to accomplish this.

Comment: @MikeM. please see my edit comment

Comment: Comment out the unload and release statements and try it out.

Comment: Is the code block in your post exactly how you have it in your project? Or did you edit it down?

Comment: @MikeM. yes its exactly like it plus the OnLoadCompleteListener

Comment: Did commenting out those lines work for you? Even if that doesn't completely solve your problem, your code still shouldn't be structured like you have it. Unloading and releasing immediately after the calls to play isn't a good idea.

Comment: @MikeM. When would u release resources?How would you solve it?

Comment: You can dump them when you know you'll no longer need them. The catch is, though, you have to give them enough time to play first. Your code, as written, tells SoundPool to begin playing the sounds, but then _immediately_ tells it to stop and dump them. As for how you should handle this, it all depends on how you need to use them. If they're just played once, e.g. at your app's startup, then your code is close; you just need to put a delay in between play and unload. If you need to use them through your app's lifetime, you shouldn't unload them until the app is closing.

Comment: Describe how you need to use them and I'll help you get it sorted out. Btw, does this mean that you got them to play when you commented out those lines?

Comment: @MikeM. im trying to release resources immediately as the sounds were played. I have tried to use the OnLoadCompleteListener.It should make the difference of the delay,shouldn't it?

Comment: Setting an OnLoadCompleteListener will have no effect on the delay. I've posted an answer that should get ya rollin'.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure where your stream_id variables came from, but you unload a sound resource with the id returned from SoundPool.load().

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unloading the sound resources and releasing the SoundPool object immediately after playing, create a Runnable to perform those tasks, and post it with a delay to a Handler. Declare the following:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable delayedUnload = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        soundPool.unload(sound_id1);
        soundPool.unload(sound_id2);
        soundPool.unload(sound_id3);
        soundPool.release();
    }
};
```

Then post the Runnable after you've played the sound resources:

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
soundPool.play(sound_id1, leftVolume, rightVolume, 1, 0, rate);
soundPool.play(sound_id2, leftVolume, rightVolume, 1, 0, rate);
soundPool.play(sound_id3, leftVolume, rightVolume, 1, 0, rate);

handler.postDelayed(delayedUnload, 5 * 1000);
```

The second parameter in `postDelayed()` is the delay in milliseconds; in this case, the delay is 5 seconds. SoundPool does not provide a method to determine when a sound has finished playing, so you will need to adjust the delay accordingly.

Comment: where would you place the handler?

Comment: If you're referring to the first block of code in my answer, it would go outside of any method definitions in the class you're using it in. I would guess you're using an Activity, so I would put them before the onCreate method, though it doesn't have to be there. As long as it's not in a method.

Comment: My method use paramerts.How do I pass them when the method called in the run section.They are not recognized

Comment: Do you mean the sound_id variables? If so, declare them the same way you do the Runnable; in the Activity, outside any methods. You won't need to pass them; the Runnable will have access to them as well.

Comment: thnx a lot for your help! I will try it